# What Scopes Required For UserInfo Endpoint - Besides 'openid'?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4 with .NET Core.

I can successfully log in using grant type ResourceOwnerPassword ('password'), then I immediately call the UserInfo endpoint. That call fails, and when I check the server log I see:

- 'Scope validation failed. Return 403'
  and
- 'Scopes found on current principal: scope: **openid**, scope: profile, scope: roles, scope: api1, scope: offline_access'

The docs say 'at least the openid scope is required', which the log shows I have, but the docs also say, right before that, '...Depending on the granted scopes...' - what scopes? Where is it designated what scopes are required by the UserInfo endpoint? I'm assuming I'm missing it/them, but no idea what. I have correct scopes to successfully hit the token endpoint (/connect/token), but not the right scope(s) to successfully call the userinfo endpoint (/connect/userinfo).

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Buzz

Answer (score 0):

The userinfo endpoint has a minimum requirement for the `openid` scope.

Here's the test that proves that:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/test/IdentityServer.IntegrationTests/Clients/UserInfoClient.cs#L41

Comment: I wasn't questioning the minimum requirement of openid; as I say in the post I already have the openid scope, I'm wondering what scope is required in **addition** to openid. As mentioned in your docs that say "...Depending on the granted scopes...". I assume this means some other scopes may also be required, because I have openid and I get the error "Scope validation failed"

Comment: All I am saying is, when you send a token containing the openid scope to userinfo, it will be accepted (regardless of which other scopes you sent along). You seem to say this is not the case. How did you define the openid scope in your config?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out - I was missing an **AllowedScope** on the call to the UserInfo endpoint. When I added the scope here in the Startup.Configure() method it worked:

```
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions 
    {
       Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
       AllowedScopes = { "api1", "WebAPI" },
       RequireHttpsMetadata = false
    });
```

The thing I don't understand is how the login itself was working. The scopes are sent in on the call to login (/connect/token) - and that succeeded. I thought these scopes were for authentication, as the name for this class here is '..AuthenticationOptions'. My guess is these are options *during* login but not *for* login, and they're only used when you go out to access a resource, such as /connect/userinfo. Maybe someone who knows can confirm this.

Thanks for your help!

Buzz